# The system cannot find the file specified in uft 12.01

Tags: hp-uft

I was trying to use Insight feature of UFT to avoid using the build configuration of libraries from development side for a flex based application. When i tried using the method "GetVisibleText" UFT 12.01 returns "The system cannot find the file specified". But i was click on different buttons in the same page Example buttton x, Button y at my wish. So it means UFT is distinguishes the objects. My purpose is to check on the dynamic text objects in the page. Note : "GetRoProperty" returned nothing  and there is only one property called "similarity" and its returning a constant value at all the times immaterial of different pages.

Comment: Some code.. would be really useful. See this on [ask]

Comment: temp = Browser("").InsightObject("RightBottom_text").GetTOProperty("similarity")...temp will always return same value at different pages.

Comment: temp = Browser("").InsightObject("RightBottom_text").GetVisibleText ...returns the exception as shown in the attachment

Answer (score 0):

UFT's Insight technology uses images in order to identify objects, the fact that it identifies button <kbd>x</kbd> does not mean that it has any intrinsic understanding that it contains the text "*x*".

In Insight the *similarity* property is used in order to decide how dissimilar a control has to be from the captured image in order for it not to constitute a match. *Similarity* isn't a regular identification property as we are used to. This is why you get the same value for each test object (it doesn't mean that the specific object supports this property).

Regarding `GetVisibleText`, UFT uses [OCR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_character_recognition) in order to extract the text. You can specify which language you're expecting in the last parameter.

In any case none of these things should fail due to not being able to find a file. I have two thoughts on the matter:

1. Are you using descriptive programming to identify the `InsightObject` (see link further on) if so perhaps the image file you specified isn't found?
2. What OCR Mechanism are you using? (Tools ⇒ Options ⇒ GUI Testing ⇒ Text Recognition), perhaps the mechanism you're using isn't installed correctly and this is causing the failure, try using a different OCR mechanism.

You can read a bit more about [Insight here](http://community.hpe.com/t5/All-About-the-Apps/A-guide-to-Image-Based-Testing-with-HP-UFT-s-Insight/ba-p/6355855#.VqZ6OIgrKUk).